# Removing 'PERSON' ents from text?

Tags: nlp, spacy

```py
>>> import spacy
>>> en = spacy.load('en')
>>> text = "Joe is walking down the street. He is wondering if Dan Jordan will be home soon."
>>> doc = en(text)
>>> people = [e for e in doc.ents if e.label_ == 'PERSON']
>>> print(people)
[Joe, Dan Jordan]
>>> print(doc.ents)
(Joe, Dan Jordan)
```

I'd like to be able to remove or replace all ents with a label, in this case 'PERSON'--so somehow obtain "x is walking down the street. He is wondering if x will be home soon".

What's the best approach for this? I imagine you'd have to somehow retokenize doc and remove/replace the 'PERSON' strings, but I'm not sure how to check whether a token is an ent and whether than ent has the 'PERSON' label while iterating through the doc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a token extension which is unlike other fields mutable and where you will store the information you need. In this case, you can copy the text of every token and then anonymize the entities by changing this.

```py
import spacy
spacy.tokens.token.Token.set_extension('anonymized', default='')
text = "Joe is walking down the street. He is wondering if Dan Jordan will be home soon."
doc = en(text)
people = [e for e in doc.ents if e.label_ == 'PERSON']
for tok in doc: 
    tok._.anonymized = tok.text
for ent in people:
    ent[0]._.anonymized = "X"
    for i in range(1, len(ent)):
        ent[i]._.anonymized = ''
"".join([tok._.anonymized + (" " if tok.whitespace_ else "")
         for tok in doc if tok._.anonymized])
```

And you get:

```
'X is walking down the street. He is wondering if X will be home soon.'
```

You will probably need to do the detokenization more carefully.